# Получение COUNT(*) из двух таблиц одним запросом

Tags: mysql

такой вопрос уже есть, но ответа на него нет.

Требуется в одном запросе получить COUNT() из двух разных таблиц.

Таблица 1:

[image: Таблица 1]

Таблица 2:

[image: Таблица 2]

Ожидаемый результат:

[image: Ожидаемый результат]

Результат, который получается:

[image: Результат]

Код, который работает не правильно:

`SELECT COUNT(event.id), COUNT(postback.id) FROM event,postback WHERE DATE(postback.date) BETWEEN '2020-01-22' AND '2020-01-23' AND postback.cid = 22 AND event.c_id = 22 GROUP BY event.id, postback.id`

Требуется получить с двух таблиц COUNT(), у который c_id и cid равны 22

Comment: `SELECT cnt1, cnt2 FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt1 FROM table1), (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt1 FROM table2)`. Ну и в каждый подзапрос затолкать соответствующий WHERE.

Comment: При выполнении: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Ну добавьте алиасы, какие сложности-то?

Comment: Напишите это решение в ответ, отмечу как правильное. Спасибо большое, всё получилось!

Comment: Да ну... вроде решение-то очевидное. Если и мешает что его найти, так это обычная зашоренность - если две таблицы, так сперва связываем, потом считаем. А то, что связывать можно и подзапросы - забылось... хочешь - сам напиши решение как ответ - но уж тогда постарайся с объяснениями. А мне - ну извини, просто лень.